# how to auto close Materialize css mobile navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, materialize

I have created a website [Link](https://gourisevapeeth.org.in/). Here I have used Only Materialize css and vanilla js, Plain Css. I have made a single page application where page sections are being hidden or showing using event listeners. It works fine. However, In the mobile navbar, the menu is not auto-closing after taping on it. I didn't find any docs relating to autoclose in this specific matter. How I can close the navbar whenever the user taps on a menu option?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.sidenav-close` to every link in the sidenav. From the documentation:

**Close Trigger**

Add the class `.sidenav-close` to an element inside the sidenav and any click event on that element will cause the sidenav to close. This is useful in Single Page Apps where the page does not refresh on link clicks.

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
  <li><a class="sidenav-close" href="#!">Clicking this will close Sidenav</a></li>
</ul>
```